# How to edit two divs simultaneously using AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, forms, jquery

Can any one tell me how this functionality can be achieved where you edit the left text field and it updates the text field on the right. 
My guess is using AJAX. I want to use it too. How do I go about it. What needs to be done.
this is the link.http://printbindaas.com/bjp

Comment: So what have you tried? You don't need ajax for that...

Comment: Could you please add some more information about what you want and what you already have tried? So we know with what you have a problem.

Comment: I want to use this functionality ...But was not sure what was used in this site AJAX or JAVASCRIPT...?..

Comment: Don't want to sounds like a bitch, but I suggest you start reading into what javascript / ajax is. And what it does.

Comment: The page you reference doesn't use either jQuery or Ajax. It uses plain ol' javascript to update the card with the text the user enters into the input fields. My best advice: learn javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Just regular javascript. On the `keyup` event the right div gets the same contents as the left div.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `data-` element on each of your inputs which has the ID of the div that it relates to, i.e.:

```
<input data-rel="name" type="text" name="name" />
<div id="name" />

$(':input').on('change keyup', function() {
    var rel = $(this).data('rel');
    if (rel) {
        $('#' + rel).text(this.value);
    }
});
```

or alternatively, use the `name` field of the input:

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
<div id="field_name" />

$(':input').on('change keyup', function() {
     $('#field_' + this.name).text(this.value);
});
```

Comment: how should I use this Jquery Function. as there are many  DIVs i.e text , Email , Address all are different divs . That means I will have to copy paste this code hundred times..?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/JpUuk/

HTML:

```
Name: <input type="text" id="name">
<div style="border: 1px solid black">Your name is: <span id="name_out"></span></div>
```

JavaScript (with jQuery):

```
$('#name').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#name_out').html(this.value);
})
```

Or using plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('name').onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById('name_out').innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value;
};
```